# Sort a list of points by distance between consecutive points

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, sorting, distance, point

I have a List(Of Point) - with possibly hundreds of thousands of points. The only way I can use it, it seems, to draw something properly, is to sort it by the distance between them.

[ I have used a CCL and convex hull on the set, but the result is still a mass of tight hashes - or nice radiating lines if I sort them afterwards by angle from center, or slope, or something ]

Is there any way to sort a list of points by the distance between consecutive points ?

I have used

```
Dim orderedByX As List(Of Point) = listOfPoints.OrderBy(Function(pt) pt.X).ToList()
```

Comment: Do you have distance between all pairs of points?

Comment: I have a list of points, and all the points are distinct.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?? Reconstruct a non-convex polygon from a list of unordered points??

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to convert your list of points into a list of lines, then sort by line distance?

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Only if I created lines between every combination of points, and that would be huge... and I wouldn't know which matches which point

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda yes - only I would like to get a convex polygon. I have applied a convex hull algorithm to the set, but I still get intersecting lines over the polygon. It may be because between the point where I do this processing (in lat/lon) and where the points get displayed (in pixels that really represent meters) the meaning of x and y is changing... so the lat/lon may not translate to rectangular coordinates...

Comment: Seems to me that if you apply the convex hull algorithm, you should save that list of points (those that make up the convex hull) in an ordered list. If you're having trouble displaying the convex hull, then your problem is in your transformation from lat/long to pixels.

Comment: Yes, that is quite possible - and that is why I don't know if what I see is wrong - if I try to plot the lat/lon coordinates for each set, by hand, they seem ok - but when converted in meters, using a perspective transform, they are slanted - so I end up with vertices slashing through what I would thing is a convex shape. Sorting by distance mostly fixed this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forst need to construct `point, distance` pairs. You can, for example, do that by zipping the list with a shifted version of the same list. Then you sort the sequence by the distance and select the points corresponding to the distances.

```
Dim sortedPoint = listOfPoints.Zip(listOfPoints.Skip(1), Function(p1, p2) New With { .Point = p2, .Distance = (p2 - p1).Length }).OrderBy(Function(v) v.Distance).Select(Function(v) v.Point)
```

I still think that this is not what you really want. I think that the resulting list is rather useless.

Comment: Wow this is so nice ! I did this, eventually, by finding the min distance, finding the point that has that distance, to each point - then adding it to a new list and removing it from the current list... But wow ! I got it to work eventually, though I will definitely try this too. Thank you.

Comment: This line of code is quite easy. First we have a list of points - `p[i]`. Then we glue the previous point to each point, getting a sequence of `{p[i-1], p[i]}` which we immediately turn into `{Point=p[i], Distance=(p[i]-p[i-1]).Length}`. We then sort the sequence by distance and extract the points.

Comment: :) what is the definition of "easy" in Linq ? (or, is there anything that can't be written in a single line ?)

Comment: Well... LINQ surely is sweet =) On a serious note, LINQ doesn't have "branching"/"T-junctions", so any branching has to be done in multiple lines. I cheated around that by writing `listOfPoints` twice, but if it was not a list, but a stream from a database, I'd need a second line and enough memory to fit all  points.